# Surjective and full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, numerical-optimization

We have a linear mapping $f: \mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$, $x \mapsto Cx$, defined by a matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m \leq n$. How can I show that $f$ being surjective is equivalent to the matrix $C$ having full rank.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I looked for proofs of surjectivity and full rank but I just do not know how to start. Maybe you can give me a hint.

Comment: The rank is the maximum number of linearly independent columns.

Comment: I know but how can I show that the linear independant columns are equivalent to the surjectivity of the function f (I know how surjectivity is defined).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f$ is surjective if and only if for every vector $y \in \Bbb R^m$, the system of equations $Cx = y$ has at least one solution.  Based on what you know about solving systems of equations: if **every** choice of $y$ yields a solution, what can you deduce about the matrix $C$?

Comment: That every Column is linearly independant and thus of full rank?

Comment: @Moschine not quite. In fact, if $m<n$ then the columns **cannot** be linearly independent.